# how to loop through draw.rectangle in pillow python?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, python-imaging-library

I want to retrieve face coordinates from a JSON file that looks like this:

```
#Beginning PART OF JSON FILE
{
    "image": {
        "height": 2160,
        "orientation": 1,
        "width": 3840
    },
    "objects": [
        {
            "boundingBox": {
                "height": 1152,
                "width": 1048,
                "x": 0,
                "y": 977
            },
            "type": "person"
        },
        {
            "boundingBox": {
                "height": 1305,
                "width": 486,
                "x": 1096,
                "y": 852
            },
            "type": "person"
        },...
....
```

PYTHON CODE:

```
import PIL
import json
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw

with open('facecoordinates.json','r') as f:
    data = json.load(f)

height = d["objects"] [0] ["boundingBox"] ["height"]
width = d["objects"] [0] ["boundingBox"] ["width"]
xx = d["objects"] [0] ["boundingBox"] ["x"]
yy = d["objects"] [0] ["boundingBox"] ["y"]

image = Image.open('vlcsnap.png')


imgcp = image.copy()
imgcp_draw = ImageDraw.Draw(imgcp)


imgcp_draw.rectangle([xx,yy,(width+xx),(yy+height)], fill = None, outline = "red")

imgcp.save('DC1.jpg')
imgcp.show()
```

I managed to pull the first coordinates from the JSON file and map the face but i want to know how to loop through and pass all face-coordinates to draw boxes in image.

i am trying to loop through them to `Pillow.DRAW.RECTANGLE` as coordinates to draw the box on image.

i have been struggling to get past the loops and its always wrong. any suggestions?

Comment: You are doing wrong at the second loop. `i` is not there where you are iterating list. Here: `for v in  i['boundingBox']`

Comment: what is wrong exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to correct the way how you are putting in coordinates in `Pillow.DRAW.RECTANGLE`.

Your code will look like this:

```py
list=data['objects']

# After following Mark's edit

coords_list = [] 
for i in list: 
   coords = [] 
   coords.append(i['boundingBox']['x']) 
   coords.append(i['boundingBox']['y']) 
   coords.append(i['boundingBox']['x'] + i['boundingBox']['width']) 
   coords.append(i['boundingBox']['y'] + i['boundingBox']['height']) 
   coords_list.append(coords) 

image = Image.open('vlcsnap.png')
imgcp = image.copy()
imgcp_draw = ImageDraw.Draw(imgcp)

for coord in  coords_list:
     imgcp_draw.rectangle(coord, fill = None, outline = "red")

imgcp.save('DC1.jpg')
imgcp.show()
```

**Edited by Mark Setchell beyond this point**

The `draw()` functions take `x0,y0,x1,y1` rather than a width and height so you need code more like this.

```
coords_list = [] 
for i in list: 
   coords = [] 
   coords.append(i['boundingBox']['x']) 
   coords.append(i['boundingBox']['y']) 
   coords.append(i['boundingBox']['x'] + i['boundingBox']['width']) 
   coords.append(i['boundingBox']['y'] + i['boundingBox']['height']) 
   coords_list.append(coords)
```

Comment: thanks for replying, i tried this but get an error:
``` values_list.append(list(i['boundingBox'].values()))
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable```

Comment: after running the edited code its taking only the Y values and not iterating through the list properly,
im trying to get the (height,width,x,y) values into the draw.rectangle

Comment: Can you add the output of values_list?

Comment: I have made a minor change after updating first time.

Comment: You have to do `values_list.append(values)` instead of `values_list.append(v)`

Comment: I have helped you in supplying the values correct to the rectangle and It is correct what I see in the documentation. https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.0.x/reference/ImageDraw.html#PIL.ImageDraw.PIL.ImageDraw.Draw.rectangle

Comment: i have updated the code and i managed to map 1 face correctly can you update your code

Comment: I hope you don't mind I updated your code a bit - feel free to change it back how you like, it was  just too much for a comment and I didn't want to steal your points by answering myself.

Comment: @J.Doe Can you check once again.

Comment: thank you it finally worked i don't think i would have came up with this solution, i understand the logic but the implementation was spinning my head. but now i understand